# Creating custom AMI for AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-data-pipeline

I've read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-custom-ami.html on how to create a custom AMI for use with AWS Data Pipeline. The document mostly makes sense except for the last line:

> "Create and configure a user account named ec2-user."

What does this mean? What credentials (if any?) do I use for this AMI user? What SSH key do I allow to log in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypair that you should use can be specified in EC2 resource definition.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-resources-vpc.html

In case of the above EC2 resource snippet, my-key-pair would have a PEM file associated with it.  Your ec2-account should correspond to that PEM file so that DPL can login to that EC2 resource.